# Autocorrelation Functions/Autocorrelograms and the assumption of Weak Stationarity?

Tags: autocorrelation, stationarity

Does it make sense to even speak of the autocorrelation function or of the autocorrelogram for a non-weakly stationary series? Anytime we see an autocorrelation function or an autocorrelogram can we immediately deduce that the random process must have necessarily been assumed to be (at least) weakly stationary?